# HTML5 canvas image object don't work

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm using a function to return an image object with HTML5 canvas, but I always have an error alert (onerror event)

```
function GetThatImage() {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "http://localhost/assets/images/loadedsprite.png";
    image.onerror = alert('Oops... Image isn\'t loaded: '+image.src);
    return image;
}
```

Can anyone help me ? 
Thanks
(sorry for my bad english)

EDIT: with this code, I have first an alert 'oops image is not loaded...' then I have 'image loaded'

```
function GetThatImage() {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "http://localhost/assets/images/loadedsprite.png";
    image.onload = function() {
        alert('image loaded');
    };
    image.onerror = alert('Oops... Image isn\'t loaded: '+image.src);
    return image;
}
```

Comment: `image.onerror = alert(...)` calls `alert(...)` and assigns the return value of this call as the `onerror` handler. Wrap the `alert(...)` in an anonymous function and assign this to `.onerror` -> `.onerror = function() { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the event `onerror` with an anonymous function like `image.onload`.

```
image.onerror = function () { 
    alert('Oops... Image isn\'t loaded: '+image.src);
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! and how can I preload the image.src please ?